# What kind of obfuscation is this

Tags: java, obfuscation

I saw some Java applications that have code like this:

```
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method     java/lang/Object."":()V
   4: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method     printOne:()V
       3: invokestatic  #2                  // Method     printOne:()V
       6: invokestatic  #3                  // Method     printTwo:()V
       9: return        

  public static void printOne();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #4                  // Field     java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #5                  // String Hello World
       5: invokevirtual #6                  // Method     java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return        

  public static void printTwo();
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method     printOne:()V
       3: invokestatic  #2                  // Method     printOne:()V
       6: return        
}
```

And I wanted to know which kind of obfuscation is this, and what are the tools that can obfuscate a JAR file like that.

Comment: That's JVM byte code assembler. You can use `javac` to generate it.

Comment: He means javap. Javac turns source code into byte code. Javap deassembles it.

Comment: Most IDEs have a decompiler as a plugin. In use fernflower which will turn the byte code back into java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `javap -c` on a compiled java class and you will get java byte code. That's not obfuscation, rather de-compilation.  A pretty good resource from IBM is [Java bytecode:Understanding bytecode makes you a better programmer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/it-haggar_bytecode/)

Answer (score 1):

that is what `javac` generated - the compiler for the java code. It's actually really easy to transpose that to code:

```
public class Test {
   // an implicit constructor:
   public Test(){

   }

   public static void testOne(){
      System.out.println("Hello World");
   }

   public static String testTwo(){
      testOne();
      testOne();
   }

}
```